# How to debug nested makefiles?

Tags: debugging, makefile, multiple-makefiles

In a large & complex projects with multi levels compossible (`include system.mk, etc.) makefile scripts as well as multiple inter modules dependencies (one Makefile calling make on another Makefile), how one (not the authors), can quickly learn those dependencies in order to debug them?

Is there a tool that can be used to graph these files/variables dependencies to help understand the "landscape" and/or to help with debugging these web of Makefiles including passing of macros/env variables?

I've primarily used
make -n for simple Makefile for dry-run
make SHELL="bash -x" -d for debugging -- this dumps lots of information which is difficult to decipher